Can this chunk of python code be speed up?
I have the following code that I want to speed up:
import numpy as np

def do_calc(a, b, d, sum_)->None:
    idx = np.ndindex(a.shape[:1]) 
    sum_[:] = 0
    for i in idx:
       sum_[0:d[i[0]]] -= a[i, 0:d[i[0]]][0]
       sum_[d[i[0]]] += b[i, d[i[0]]][0]
    return sum_


a=np.ones((5,10), order='F')
b=np.ones((5,10), order='F')*10

sum_ = np.empty(a.shape[1])

d = [8,5,2,7,1]
do_calc(a, b, d, sum_)


So a and b are 5x10 arrays that are static and I want to sum them up into sum_, a 1d-array length 10 as follows:

for each row i of b, I only want to include index d[i], that is b[i, d[i]], which will go into position sum_[d[i]]

for each row i of a, I want to include all the values up to the index d[i], that is a[i, 0:d[i]], which will go into positions sum_[0:d[i]]


in this example we have:

a= array([[1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
          [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
          [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
          [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
          [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.]])

b= array([[10., 10., 10., 10., 10., 10., 10., 10., 10., 10.],
          [10., 10., 10., 10., 10., 10., 10., 10., 10., 10.],
          [10., 10., 10., 10., 10., 10., 10., 10., 10., 10.],
          [10., 10., 10., 10., 10., 10., 10., 10., 10., 10.],
          [10., 10., 10., 10., 10., 10., 10., 10., 10., 10.]])

d= [8, 5, 2, 7, 1]

sum_= array([-5.,  6.,  7., -3., -3.,  8., -2.,  9., 10.,  0.])

I have tried the following:

Using Fortan order since we are copying over the last index mostly
sum_ is passed on to the do_calc function so that it does not have to be initiated every time. There is a big loop around the last 2 lines, where we generate new values for d and run do_calc every time.
Using ndindex to iterate over the rows.

I wonder if this could be done more efficiently since this part is what the code is spending all the time on. And in reality a and b are not constant, so we can't make use of that in this example.

If you can please provide context about the need for such a function I am happy to adjust my response but given your function I was able to simply the code to the following.
def docal2(a: np.array, b: np.array, d: np.array, sum_: np.array) -> np.array:
    r, c = a.shape
    sum_[:] = 0
    for i in range(r):
        ii = d[i]
        sum_[0:ii] -= a[i, 0: ii]
        sum_[ii] += b[i, ii]
    return sum_

This should prevent unecessay slicing of your original data and speed up the computation significantly. If you can provide further context I am happy to help you even vectorize the calculation instead of raw iterations.
Few points:

a[i, 0:d[i[0]]][0] is equivalent to a[i, 0:i] since you always need 0th element for your computation. same goes for b[i, d[i[0]]][0]
instead of np.ndindex(a.shape[:1]) use range to simplify downstream indexing like i[0]. You can directly use i for indexing.


Compare with original function
def timeit(func):
    import time
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        start = time.time()
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        return result, time.time() - start
    return wrapper

Test:
loss_holder = dict()


for rng in range(100, 10_000, 100):
    sub_holder = []
    for _ in range(10):
        a = np.ones((rng, 10)) * 1.
        b = np.ones((rng, 10)) * 10.
        d = np.random.choice(10, rng)
        
        sum_= np.array([-5.,  6.,  7., -3., -3.,  8., -2.,  9., 10.,  0.])
        
        r1, t1 = do_calc(a, b, d, sum_)
        r2, t2 = docal2(a, b, d, sum_)

        if not all(r1 == r2):
            raise ValueError(f"r1: {r1}, r2: {r2}")
        
        loss = t1 / (t2 if t2 != 0 else 1e-100)
        sub_holder.append(loss)

    loss_holder[rng] = np.mean(sub_holder)


import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


plt.plot(loss_holder.keys(), loss_holder.values())
plt.ylim(0, 6)



Thanks for taking a look. On the second point, I am not taking the 0th element. I really need a[i, 0:d[i]] to be added to the sum. The [0] at the end was needed to make it a 1d array. On using the ndindex,  think it is indeed better to drop it as I am not getting much use of it. The idea of passing the sum every time is so I don’t need to allocate memory for it every time the function is called, that seemed like an expensive operation? Oh, and d are the time of death, for each policy holder, a are the recurring premium payments and b is the death benefit.

thank you for your clarification. Based on your comment I made a few changes. After timing the functions, the new version is consistently around 3-4 times faster.

Great, that works! Like always, I now found another part of the code that is slowest and needs some attention. The issue is now the random draws which are taking too long as I am using np.searchsorted to lookup the Uniform(0,1) random draw in the cdf of the deaths distribution. But I think I can fix that by computing the inverse of cdf for a finite amount of points and then just use those as an approximation.
